# Можно ли в SQLite сделать ссылку внешнего ключа сразу на несколько строк?

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть учебное задание с таблицей сущностей и атрибутов. Так вот, в одном из атрибутов внешний ключ ссылается сразу на несколько строк в другой таблице и я не понимаю, можно ли вообще так делать или это ошибка? Пытался прописать как-то ссылку на несколько строк - ошибка, может писал неправильно?
В гугле ответа не нашёл. Редактирую БД через DB Browser. Немного не уточнил, таблица в эксель, которая отражает сущности и атрибуты нам и дана...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *в одном из атрибутов внешний ключ ссылается сразу на несколько строк в другой таблице* Покажите это конкретными CREATE TABLE, потому как звучит странно...

Comment: добавил скрин в пост

Comment: Скрин - это ниачём. Показывайте SQL-кодом создания связанных таблиц (CREATE TABLE) и примером связанных данных в виде INSERT INTO.

Comment: скрины создания добавил, мой вопрос в том, можно ли сделать ссылку внешнего ключа сразу на несколько строк? Условно ссылка из таблицы "Товар" со строки "firm,m\j,razmer" на таблицу "Состав" и на строки 
firm;
m\j;
razmer;

Comment: Я в принципе не вижу на приведённых фотографиях внешних ключей. *можно ли сделать ссылку внешнего ключа сразу на несколько строк?* Нет. Просто ссылку, без контроля со стороны соответствующей подсистемы сервера (и с интерпретацией факта связи на клиенте) - можно. PS. Вы уверены, что имеете в виду ссылку именно на несколько записей, а не ссылку на несколько полей одной записи?

Comment: Я имел ввиду ссылку на несколько полей, да

Comment: Тогда в таблице, на которую надо сослаться, создаёте вычисляемое поле, которое объединяет эти отдельные поля с нужным форматированием, создаёте по нему уникальный индекс, и делаете на это поле внешнюю ссылку из ссылающейся таблицы. Поскольку поле индексировано, его можно сделать виртуальным. Конечно, текущая версия SQLite должна поддерживать вычисляемые поля.